# How to change massage size when sending queue between two Linux computers?

Tags: linux, protocols

I'm doing research on different communication protocols used in Internet of Things (IoT).

I'm sending "Hello" massage from one Raspberry Pi to another,because I want to measure speed, bandwidth etc.

How could I set massage size? I would like to try sending 32 bytes massages up to 4032 bytes massages.

Edit: I'm testing MQTT, AMQP and SOAP communication protocols.

Comment: are you using MQTT protocol? or what protocols do you want to test?

Comment: I'm testing AMQP, MQTT and SOAP protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check nats.io [Benchmark and Tune NATS](https://nats.io/documentation/tutorials/nats-benchmarking/).

It mainly focuses on nats.io but the output could be used to bench your systems against other protocols.

Here you could find more info about how it is being used for [IoT](https://nats.io/tags/iot/).

Regarding the message size https://nats.io/documentation/faq/#msgsize:

> NATS does have a message size limitation that is enforced by the server and communicated to the client during connection setup. Currently, the limit is 1MB.